# socket_connect keeps failing with permission denied

Tags: laravel, sockets, laravel-5, websocket

I am running into the following error message:

```
socket_connect(): unable to connect [61]: Connection refused
```

The code that I am using:

```
$address = 'localhost';
$port = 5600;
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_connect($socket, $address, $port);
```

I was trying this out on a valet .dev environment with nginx so I guessed it might have to do with not having a proper development environment that supports websockets but after testing I am getting the exact same on my homestead vagrant environment.

Any help with getting more verbose debugging information or a possible solution would be amazing.

All suggestions are welcome.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server was not running properly. I could not map the code 61 to any error message by searching for it online.

If anybody encounters this with a code 61 I suggest looking at your websocket server and check if it is running properly.